How to normalize a mode matrix
I have a mode matrix and i want to normalize it, so each mode has the largest mode displacement equal to 1. The mode matrix in question is
{{0.244806, -0.425193, 0.223607},
 {-0.193219, -0.0394207, 0.223607},
 {0.140068, 0.190849, 0.223607}}

. I used this function N[Map[#/Max[#] &, eigVecs, {1}]]
to normalize the matrix but the problem is, that this function doesnt account for max negative values of the matrix. I asked ChatGPT and it said to use this Map[#/Max[Abs[#]] &, eigVecs, {1}]], but again this function has problems. The chatgpt function gets the correct relative normalized values but ignores the signs (+,-), or rather it flips the signs the wrong way. Can someone help.
P.S. This are my initial calculations for the mode matrix:
M = {{30, 0, 0}, {0, 25, 0}, {0, 0, 20}};
k = {{86888, -56888, 0}, {-56888, 99554, -42666}, {0, -42666, 
    42666}};
{eigVals, eigVecs} = Eigensystem[{k, M}];
\[Omega] = N[Sqrt[eigVals]];
\[Phi] = N[MatrixForm[eigVecs]]


Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory Tour now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by clicking the gray triangles, because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by clicking the checkmark sign! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Please give your code in a way that can be directly copied and tested by others. this way you might get help. Giving an example of the mode matrix might also be useful

Based on your comment that one of your attempts "flips the signs the wrong way", I'm assuming that you want something like this:
init = {{0.244806, -0.425193, 0.223607}, 
        {-0.193219, -0.0394207, 0.223607}, 
        {0.140068, 0.190849, 0.223607}};

init / First@*MaximalBy[Abs] /@ init
(* {{-0.575753, 1., -0.525895}, 
    {-0.864101, -0.176295, 1.}, 
    {0.626403, 0.853502, 1.}} *)

